# Android Action Bar: Changing the color of Action Buttons

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, actionbarsherlock, android-theme

I have an app with an action bar that looks like this:

[image: http://postimage.org/image/ozwy8o4x7/]

I would like the text of the menu action buttons "Home" and "Logout" to be white as well. How can I change their text color?

Let me know if you want to see any code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As i perceive it this is a simple attribute called `android:actionMenuTextColor`.

To use it properly you should create your own styles, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="myTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionBarText</item>
    </style>

    <style name="myTheme.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/myTheme.ActionBar.Text</item>
    </style>

    <style name="myTheme.ActionBar.Text" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionBarText</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

And then set @color/actionBarText to the color of your choice. You can also define other values here like for instance background color.

Comment: Thanks for your response! That changed the text color. Would you happen to know if there's a way to make the little divider between "Home" and "Logout" white as well?

Comment: Set the android:actionBarDivider attribute to what ever you want in the same way. =)
And don't forget to upvote and accept my answer if you find it useful.